# Recycler view with sqlite kotlin

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin, android-recyclerview, adapter

I am trying to delete the SQLite DB notes and using kotlin and rendering is done by recyclerview. But my delete won't do the job, it's not deleting. Very new to this please help.

holder class

```
class MyHolder (Itemview : View):RecyclerView.ViewHolder(Itemview) {

var titleHolder: TextView = Itemview.findViewById(R.id.tv_title)

var descriptionHolder: TextView = Itemview.findViewById(R.id.tv_content)

var imgEditHolder: ImageView = Itemview.findViewById(R.id.im_edit)

var imgDeleteHolder: Button = Itemview.findViewById(R.id.im_delete)  
}


Adapter Onbindervieewholder  method


override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyHolder, position: Int) {

            var Mynotes = noteLiist[position]

            holder.titleHolder.text = Mynotes.nodeTitle
            holder.descriptionHolder.text = Mynotes.nodeDescritption
            holder.imgDeleteHolder.setOnClickListener {
                View.OnClickListener {
                    val dbManager = SqlDBManager(this.context!!)
                    val selectionArgs = arrayOf(Mynotes.nodeID.toString())
                    dbManager.Delete("ID=?", selectionArgs)
                    LoadQuery("%")
                }
            }

        }



[![db manager class][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/D6SjZ.png
```

Comment: Please share the snippet of Delete() method.

Comment: Here is the delete method used under SQLdbManager 






fun Delete(selection:String,selectionArgs:Array<String>):Int{
        val count = sqlDB!!.delete(dbTable,selection,selectionArgs)
        return count
    }

Comment: @SoumikBhattacharjee you can share the workable code with rview and sqlite delete... If you can.

Comment: Can you share the code of **SQLdbManager** class.. You have to open the database before accessing it , have you done it on your  SQLdbManager class??

Comment: I have updated the pic url  above @SoumikBhattacharjee

Comment: Given an answer, check and let me know if it works or not.

Answer (score 0):

On your onClickListener after initializing your database class, do this:

```
val data = dbManager.DatabaseHelperNotes(context).writableDatabase
data.delete("table_name","where clause",null)
```